# Drag and Drop в java для android

Tags: java

Всем доброе время суток! =)
Я пишу приложение для Android. У меня есть Activity, который задан AbsoluteLayout и там несколько ImageView. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы мои ImageView можно было перемещать по экрану пользователем? А еще как ставить на определенное место определенный ImageView? =)) Очень много читала, искала.. понимаю что нужен Drag and drop, но никак не пойму как реализовать 
Заранее большое спасибо =)

Answer (score 4):

AbsoluteLayout - история, попрощайтесь с ним...

Вот материал по теме в виде удобного туториала:
[Drag and Drop by Vogells](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) и на [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: Не знал... А что случилось с `AbsoluteLayout` то?

Comment: Он уже очень очень очень давно deprecated и везде всюду пишут не использовать его )

Comment: Упс, даже и не знал... Наверное потому, что никогда не использовал и даже не пытался